# Bind Complex Object to Angular 6 Reactive Form Checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular 6 and I am using Reactive Forms. I have a data source that uses a composite key of applicationVersion and applicationBuild.

```
[{
    "applicaitionVersion":"1",
    "applicationBuild":"2",
    "label": "Build 1.2"
}, 
{   
    "applicaitionVersion":"1",
    "applicationBuild":"3",
    "label": "Build 1.3"
}]
```

My form generates a formArray with formControls using the data above and outputs it with the following HTML.

```
<div class="col-sm-6.col-md-4" *ngFor="let build of builds">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" [value]='build' [formControl]="formGroup.get(build.customKey)">
     {{ build.label}}
   </label>
</div>
```

When I check the checkbox. I want formGroup.value to have [value] of the checkbox instead of the just the formArray telling me whether that specific checkbox was true or false.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing this without listening to an onchange and mapping the values?